# Tinymce-4: Extract text only from a link

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

In the tinymce.activeEditor I have this line of innerHTML-code (part of an ul-list):

```
<li><a href="#">Important words</a></li>
```

I put caret somewhere in the sentence "Important words", click a button with this line of code as part of the onclick-event:

```
seltxt = editor.selection.select(editor.selection.getNode()).text;
```

This selects/highlight the text "Important words" as it should, but unfortunally also the surrounding `<a href>…</a>`. I don't want that, only the clean text between those a-tags.
I've seen close to houndres of select-text ideas but none so fare that can filter out/schrink selection to text withouth those a-tags using some smart short Javascript code. I don't want jquery!
Can someone solve this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getSel().focusNode.textContent
```

textContent will give you the text

Comment: This works nice (gets the text content only) but does not however select it in the editor as my previous setup did (my setup selected too much :) I try tweek this a little. But, yes, it did basically what I wanted too. When I apply a background color span to it, it sets bg color span twice, both on the text (inside of a-tag as I wanted) and outside the a-tag too (as I not wanted). Weird, but tnx mate!

Comment: wc buddy, i think you are talking about background color or foreground color plugin..in that you can tweak back/forecolor plugin and check if current selection is anchor tag and if so you have to find textcontent as i did here and wrap only it with the span tag..

Comment: Tnx, yes, thats what I figuered out too. Its not a color plugin but a menu system user can change dynamically (custom plugin). Wrapping a span around the text solved a long list of probs anoying me, and all works as a breeze now.